# Defined LM339 behavior when the (+) input is floating

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet, standard

I was troubleshooting a charge indicator circuit on a tire inflator/flashlight. The green LED is supposed to light up if the battery voltage is above a certain voltage level. The LED is connected to one of the outputs of an LM339 Quad Comparator. The corresponding (-) input to that output was connected to the circuit tracing back to the battery, but the corresponding (+) input just seemed to be floating. I couldn't see any traces off of that pin going anywhere. According to the 339's [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm339.pdf), output will go HIGH (with a pull-up resistor) if the (+) input voltage is higher than the (-) input voltage.

My question: With the LM339, if the (+) input is floating, does the IC have a set percentage of VCC to "make" the (+) input?

I'm not a pro at searching through datasheets, so maybe the answer is staring me in the face and I just missed it. I *am* as sure as I can be about that pin not being connected to anything on the PCB, though.

Comment: "According to the 339's datasheet, output will go HIGH if the (-) input voltage is higher than the (+) input voltage". No. The output is open collector, and it can never go high by itself. With a pull-up resistor, it will go high when the (+) input is higher than the (-) input. See Vid in Ioh and Vol, on Page 6.

Comment: Probably, that specific comparator is just used as an inverter / current driver. Whenever the (-) input voltage goes above a certain threshold (which, frankly, I still can't tell how much it is, when the (+) input floats), the output will pull low, turning the LED on (if cathode goes to output of comparator, and anode to positive or series resistance).

Comment: If the PCB has copper on the component side, is there a chance that a small copper trace comes out of that pin, and goes underneath the IC, so that you can't see it?

Comment: That's possible. If having an input on such a comparator not connected to anything leads to truly undefined behavior, I guess it must be connected to something, even if I can't tell what by looking at it.

Comment: @Pete  If you measure voltage at at (+) input, what do you see?  What's the supply voltage (Vcc, pin 3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schematic from the datasheet:

[image]

So it seems that you have to apply a voltage lower than \$V_{CC}\$ minus two B-E junctions to have an effect on the left branch of the difference amplifier. Not connecting it will be the same as applying \$V_{CC}\$.

Comment: I don't think that the threshold is at \$V_{CC}\$. I would bet (though I'm not sure) for \$V_{CC}-(2·0.7)\$. The common-mode input voltage range includes GND (as the datasheet says), but not \$V_{CC}\$.

Comment: @Telaclavo - You're right, I didn't express myself well. I meant *in any case* lower than Vcc, without being more specific. Just to compare with the situation where you would connect the input to Vcc.

Comment: Still, your last sentence is confusing. Applying Vin(+)=Vcc implies Iin(+)=0, but Iin(+)=0 does not necessarily imply that the circuit will work as if Vin(+)=Vcc. It might imply that it works as if Vin(+)=Vcc-(2·0.7), in which case it would make some sense to use only one input, because Vin(-) could sometimes be above Vin(+), and Vout would have two states. Otherwise, with Vin(-) always <= Vin(+), it doesn't make much sense. // I'm really curious to know if Pete sees   a hidden trace or not.